# Security Transparent alternative for RuntimeHelpers.PrepareDelegate

Tags: c#, .net, code-access-security

I need to pre-JIT some emitted delegates ahead of time and tried using the [RuntimeHelpers.PrepareDelegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.runtimehelpers.preparedelegate.aspx) for this, but this method is marked with the `SecurityCritical` attribute. My assembly is marked with the `AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers` attribute and can therefore not call any security critical code.

Why are `PrepareDelegate` and `PrepareMethod` security critical and what alternatives are their that alternatives do I have in pre-JITting those delegates?

Comment: Have you tried marking the method that does the pre-JITing with `[SecuritySafeCritical]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As referenced in the MSDN article [CA2140: Transparent code must not reference security critical items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264475.aspx):

> **How to Fix Violations**
>
> To fix a violation of this rule, do one of the following:
>
> - Mark the code element that uses the security critical code with the `SecurityCriticalAttribute` attribute
>
>   *- or -*
> - Remove the `SecurityCriticalAttribute` attribute from the code elements that are marked as security critical and instead **mark them
>     with the `SecuritySafeCriticalAttribute`** or
>     `SecurityTransparentAttribute` attribute.

You have to mark the method that does the pre-JITing with the `[SecuritySafeCriticalAttribute]`. Here it is in action:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Security;

[assembly: AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers]
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            PreJIT();
        }

        [SecuritySafeCritical]
        static void PreJIT()
        {
            RuntimeHelpers.PrepareMethod(
                System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicMethod.GetCurrentMethod()
                .MethodHandle);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Further clarification: you can add that SecuritySafeCritical attribute *because* the assembly is APTCA. If it was transparent then you wouldn't be able to have safe critical code.